# Purchased and earned coins not showing

Tags: draw-something

I bought some coins for $1.99 and I appear to be earning coins, and they both don't show up. My balance remains at **0**. How can I get my coin credits?

Comment: I also have 0 coins at the moment, but I had ~150 coins yesterday. I think it's a problem with their servers.

Comment: Contact tech support and Check your bank records for the charge.

Comment: My coin balance has now been restored, if yours has not then you should do as Foxtrot said.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I had colors I bought earlier and they didn't show up and I also lost all my bombs. I had this problem for a few days and when I bought a new color scheme it showed up for a while and then I lost access.

My solution? I closed the app on my Iphone and reloaded it. Problem solved. Bombs replaced and my colors, old and new returned.